# UITabBar dissapear when dismiss UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

In my screenshot below, the structure of my storyboard are `UITabBarController` -> `UINavigationController` -> `UIViewController`. In my `UIViewController`, I call `.Camera` using  `UIImagePickerController` in my `viewDidLoad`. However, when users hit Cancel inside the camera, I dismiss the ViewController, and my tab bar dissapears!

This is my codes for dismiss:

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image]

[image]

EDIT: Added calling of UIImagePickerController

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
   {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         let picker = UIImagePickerController()
         picker.delegate = self
         picker.sourceType = .Camera
         presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

Comment: can you show the snippet, where you are presenting the `UIImagePickerController`

Comment: @AnkitThakur  Added the snippet. This `viewDidLoad` resides in `UIViewController`

Comment: it should be `navigationController.presentViewController` instead of `presentViewController` as viewcontroller is in navigation.

Comment: @AnkitThakur it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try to present the imagePicker Controller 'OverCurrentContext'

```
imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
```

or set it in the Storyboard in your UIViewController, hope it can help you.

[image]